# Calculating doses using Continual Reassessment Method

Tags: clinical-trials, dose-response

Having trouble with this problem. Doesn't seem too difficult but can't find the easiest way to set up equations to solve it. We are given beta distribution toxicity level and starting dose.

PROBLEM
We run a CRM with the model Pr(DLT at dose d) = βd and take the prior on β to be
Beta(a = 2, b = 5). The target toxicity level is 1/3. Our starting dose is d1 = 1 and our first
cohort of n1 subjects has y1 that exhibit DLT.

> (i) What dose should be used with the second cohort if we use the mean of the posterior
> distribution p(β | y1) to estimate β and then “plug this in” to get the next dose estimate?
> Also, what dose should be used with the second cohort if, instead, we use the mode of
> the posterior distribution for β as a “plug in” estimate?
>
> > (ii) What dose should be used with the second cohort if we want to ensure that no more
> > than a 10% chance that a subject is treated at a dose exceeding the MTD (i.e. we use
> > an EWOC strategy)?
> >
> > > (iii) If n1 = 1 and y1 = 0, what are the specific doses for your answers in (i) and (ii)?
> > > Also, what is the probability that the first dose, d1 = 1, exceeds the MTD given the
> > > information from this first cohort?